# Input text-box not responding on chrome [CSS/HTML]

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, input

I am having an issue getting a text input box to work correctly on Chrome. It works as it should in Firefox; however, in Chrome it is completely unresponsive. It does not display the hover effect or even allow you to type into the box. My first thought was I am missing a webkit, but I am not sure which one. (I am fairly new to CSS/html). See the code I am using below:

As you can see, it works as it should if you run the snippet.

```css
input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 60%;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #e2e2e2;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: none;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.promocode input[type="text"] {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  border: solid 0px #2c303b;
  background-color: rgba(74, 80, 99, .5);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.promocode:hover input[type="text"] {
  background-color: rgba(74, 80, 99, .8);
}

.promocode input[type="text"]:focus,
.promocode input[type="text"].focus {
  border: solid 0px #2c303b;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<div id="promoMsgPane" class="alignLeft" style="font-size: 12px; text-align:left; padding-top: 2em;                   margin-left: 0px;">
  <p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Enter your promo code below</p>
</div>


<div id="PromoIDPane">
  <div class="input-list promocode clearfix">
    <input id="txtPromoID" placeholder="Enter code" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine in my Chrome, I can see the hover effect and also can type words in the input box. I'm in Chrome version 57 on Mac. BTW, this is not related with `responsive`.

Comment: @shaochuancs I just realized it wasn't a problem with chrome after you mentioned it worked with yours. It was actually a sneaky blank div that was overlaying the text box. For some reason it didn't have any effect in firefox which is why I thought it was a styling problem with chrome. Thanks for the help anyways!